How to prove that the following function F is primitive recursive
I have this Function: f(x):  N→N
The function returns the smallest number n which is a presentation as a product of multiplying primes.
Also, n must be bigger or equal to x.
(There must be at least two different prime numbers and a prime number can appear more than once. For example, 2^3 *3.).
I need to prove that this function is a recursive primitive.
All functions proven to be primitive recursive can be used for the proof.
f(0)=6, f(1)=6,  f(2)=6,  f(3)=6,  f(4)=6,  f(5)=6,  f(6)=6,
f(7)=10,  f(8)=10,  f(9)=10,  f(10)=10,  f(11)=12,
f(12)=12,  f(13)=14,  f(14)=14,  f(15)=15,
I tried to think of a solution for this. I thought about using the function prime(x) which returns if 1 is a prime number 0 otherwise, then to make a function called
expprime()= {x^k | k >=1 and k ∈N and prime(x)=1}
from then I don't know how to continue. Would anyone be able to help me with this?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I edited it. Is it now clearer?
